# Excel vlookup looping

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

DISCLAIMER:I'm neither an expert in excel nor in vba. So I need your help in solving this.

The problem goes like this...
Consider a column having the following values

A2 Pass

A3 Pass

A4 Pass

A5 Pass

A6 Pass

A7 is the overall status cell which differs based on the valuse in the cells between A2 and A6.

The condition for values in A7 should be the following

1. If all the values in cells between A2 and A6 are Pass then A7 should be Pass
2. If even one of the values in cells between A2 and A6 is Fail then A7 should be Fail
3. If even one of the values in cells between A2 and A6 is 'No Run' or 'Not completed' or 'Not Applicable' then the cell A7 must have 'Not completed'

Pls send me the whole code incase of vba script and steps to embed this in excel or the formula for this.

I apologise if my ask is a bit too much but your assistance will be of great help for me.

Thanks in advance

SS

Comment: If **A5** is *Fail* and **A6** is *No Run*,which rule should be followed ??

Comment: 1. re: '*Pls send me the whole code ...*' This is **not** a free code writing service. If you cannot be bothered to make an attempt (and post your original effort in your question with specifics on errors received) then go hire a programmer. 2. This can be done with a nested formula; there is no VBA requirement necessary. 3. Your logic has 'holes' that are not defined in your narrative.

Comment: No! we can't and we won't ! "Pls send me the whole code" Why? We help developers, don't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and FYI I did try and googled it only then I came to know about the stackoverflow forum. I tried few things suggested but I couldnt arrive at the solution. After your comment I realized that I must have put something(to prove I have tried) even though its incorrect. Anyways thankyou very much for enlightening me on how to use a public forum like this. As I said I'm just a beginner and this is the first question I have posted in any forum.

Comment: If one of the supplied answers solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" by way of a thank you and to help other users find reliable information. Alternatively, you could put in an answer of your own and accept that ... as one of your comments below suggests might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach: write code to create a custom formula. In the VBE (Visual Basic Editor, accessed via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), add a new Module, and within it paste the following code:

```
Function Outcome(ResultRange As Range) As String

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Result As String

    Result = "Pass"

    For Each Cell In ResultRange

        If Cell.Value = "Fail" Then
            Result = "Fail"
            Exit For
        ElseIf Cell.Value = "No Run" Or Cell.Value = "Not completed" Or Cell.Value = "Not Applicable" Then
            Result = "Not completed"
        End If

    Next Cell

    Outcome = Result

End Function
```

Having done this, from the spreadsheet you have access to a new function called `OUTCOME` (you can rename it by chaning the first line of my code). If you enter the formula

```
=OUTCOME(A2:A6)
```

You'll get the result you were looking for. Note that blanks, and anything other than the values you mentioned will be treated the same as "Pass". That wouldn't be difficult to change should you wish to.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use VBA, you can implement this as a formula. Enter the below in cell A7:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,"No"&"*"),"Not Completed",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,"Pass")=5,"Pass",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,"Fail"),"Fail","Not accounted for scenario")))
```

As someone previously suggested, you may need to change the ordering of the `if` statements based on which rules should take precedence.

As others have said, you should really make an attempt at a solution and post when you're stuck, sharing what you've tried. Please bear this in mind for future. I'd suggest to understand what the above is doing you research both `COUNTIF` and `IF` functions in Excel (a quick Google will reveal plenty of resources).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to acheive the results using the countif. The below is the formula.                                                  =IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Fail")<>0,"Fail",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Not Completed")<>0,"Not Completed",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Pass")=5,"Pass",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"")=5,"No Run","Not Completed"))))

Comment: Great, glad to see you managed to find a solution. Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in A7:

=IF(AND((A2="Pass"),(A3="Pass"),(A4="Pass"),(A5="Pass"),(A6="Pass")), "True", IF(OR((A2="Not completed"),(A3="Not completed"),(A4="Not completed"),(A5="Not completed"),(A6="Not completed")), "Not Completed", IF(OR((A2="Not Applicable"),(A3="Not Applicable"),(A4="Not Applicable"),(A5="Not Applicable"),(A6="Not Applicable")), "Not Completed", IF(OR((A2="No Run"),(A3="No Run"),(A4="No Run"),(A5="No Run"),(A6="No Run")), "Not Completed", "Not Defined"))))

This is the drawn out version and possibly the version most people would start with when learning.  There is a Not Defined where you did not mention what would happen if there was a case outside what you explained.
I would encourage you to read up on IF statements.  You'll likely run across them again and even a small amount of research can go a long way.  When you're comfortable with IF statements, look up CountIF and VLookup.  If you do much in excel you'll likely run across both.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to acheive the results using the countif. The below is the formula. =IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Fail")<>0,"Fail",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Not Completed")<>0,"Not Completed",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H7,"Pass")=5,"Pass",IF(COUNTIF(H3:H‌​7,"")=5,"No Run","Not Completed")))) –